# how the slice dp is getting updated as we are passing it by value not by referebce

Tags: go, dynamic-programming

we are storing the value after it is returned how in recursion call dp is getting updated.

we are passing the code as pass by value not by reference.

from my understanding it should pass the default value of dp as we created that in main function.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func path(row, column int, obstacleGrid, dp [][]int) int {
    m := len(obstacleGrid)
    n := len(obstacleGrid[0])

    fmt.Println(row, column, dp)

    if row > m-1 || column > n-1 {
        return 0
    }
    if row == m-1 && column == n-1 {
        return 1
    }
    if obstacleGrid[row][column] == 1 {
        return 0
    }
    if dp[row][column] != -1 {
        return dp[row][column]
    }

    dp[row][column] = path(row+1, column, obstacleGrid, dp) + path(row, column+1, obstacleGrid, dp)
    return dp[row][column]
}

func main() {
    obstacleGrid := [][]int{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

    dp := make([][]int, len(obstacleGrid))
    for i := 0; i < len(obstacleGrid); i++ {
        temp := make([]int, len(obstacleGrid[0]))
        for j := 0; j < len(obstacleGrid[0]); j++ {
            temp[j] = -1
        }
        dp[i] = temp
    }
    if obstacleGrid[0][0] == 1 {
        fmt.Println(0)
        return
    }
    if obstacleGrid[len(obstacleGrid)-1][len(obstacleGrid[0])-1] == 1 {
        fmt.Println(0)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(path(0, 0, obstacleGrid, dp))
}
```

I am not able to understand the recursion for dp slice all the value should be same

Answer (score 1):

See [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro).

---

Slices in Go are implemented using a "header" that contains just enough information to describe the slice's contents. That information is the length of the slice, the capacity of the slice, and a pointer to the 0th element of the slice (this element as well as the rest of the slice's elements are stored in an *array*, sometimes referred to as the "backing", or "underlying", array of the slice).

So when you pass around a slice, you are passing around this header, these 3 values, and it is these three values that are copied every time you pass around the slice. The data itself, which is stored in the backing array, is not copied, nor would you want it to be copied (just think about what it would cost to pass around a slice containing MBs of data).

To illustrate what's being copied and what's not, you can try running the following example:

```golang
func set0(s []string, e string) {
    fmt.Printf("s=%p s[0]=%p\n", &s, &s[0])
    s[0] = e
}

func main() {
    a := []string{"foo"}
    fmt.Printf("a=%p a[0]=%p\n", &a, &a[0])
    set0(a, "bar")

    b := a
    fmt.Printf("b=%p b[0]=%p\n", &b, &b[0])
    set0(b, "baz")

    c := b
    fmt.Printf("c=%p c[0]=%p\n", &c, &c[0])
    set0(c, "quux")

    fmt.Println(a, b, c)
}

// output:
// a=0xc000010030 a[0]=0xc000014270
// s=0xc000010048 s[0]=0xc000014270
// b=0xc000010060 b[0]=0xc000014270
// s=0xc000010078 s[0]=0xc000014270
// c=0xc000010090 c[0]=0xc000014270
// s=0xc0000100a8 s[0]=0xc000014270
// [quux] [quux] [quux]
```

https://go.dev/play/p/MDbPSKcrt1P

Answer (score 0):

In Golang, slices are internally a pointer to the actual array, so any changes in the receiving function modify the actual array.

Infact when a slice is passed, it is passed with the slice capacity, length, and the pointer of the slice ( which is always pointing to the underlying array). So, if we made some change in the slice which is passed to the function by value will reflect in the slice present outside the function.

For further clarification you can read - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pass-a-slice-to-function-in-golang/